# Route incoming traffic through GRE tunnel

Tags: debian, routing, nat, gre

So I have a VPS and Dedi server both running Debian 9.9.

```
139.99.x.x: VPS
139.89.x.x: DEDI
```

The Dedi server runs a game server but can't be directly accessible, I want to route all traffic through my VPS first (obv to mask the IP of the game server).

I want to do this using a GRE tunnel. So on the dedi I did:

```
ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre remote 139.99.x.x local 139.89.x.x ttl 255
ip link set gre1 up
ip addr add 10.10.10.1/24 dev gre1
```

On the VPS:

```
ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre remote 139.89.x.x local 139.99.x.x ttl 255
ip link set gre1 up
ip addr add 10.10.10.2/24 dev gre1
```

This works I can ping both ways. I've also enabled ip forwarding in sysctl.conf.

Now I want external traffic hitting the VPS at 139.99.x.x:27015 to go through the tunnel and hit 10.10.0.1:27015 on the DEDI.

So my attempt was this which I got from another question here, on the VPS:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport -d 139.99.x.x --dports 27015 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o gre1 -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport -d 10.10.10.1 --dports 27015 -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.10.2
```

Can anybody provide me with a working example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is correct and all should work. In any issues you should use these steps to troubleshoot problems:

1. Check the iptables rules counters in the nat table with `iptables-save -c -t nat` command. Counters of rules should be non-zero. Order of rules is important if you have other rules in the nat table.
2. If the counters are zero, run the `tcpdump` to ensure there is incoming traffic.
3. Also, you should allow the forwarding packets in the firewall. The universal rule to do it: `iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED,DNAT -j ACCEPT`.
4. Run the tcpdump on the DEDI server (`tcpdump -ni gre1`) to ensure there is redirected packets from the VPS.
5. On the VPS you should allow incoming packets: `iptables -A INPUT -i gre1 -p tcp --dport 27015`.

**P.S.** Ensure that your game server uses the tcp. Most games use the udp because it's most suitable for gaming.

Comment: So yes tcp seems to work but my game server can only use UDP. Are you saying UDP is not supported?

Also, I have connection tracking disabled on my UDP game server ports. This is because a ddos overloads my CPU and fills up the connection tracking table after which connections are blocked, so I can't afford to enable connection tracking on my game server ports.

Or is connection tracking an absolute requirement?

Thanks!

Comment: I've mentioned `udp` because you specified `tcp` in your iptables rules, and it seemed suspicious. The conntrack is required to use `DNAT` and `SNAT`.

Comment: Instead disabling conntrack for UDP gaming ports try to increase conntrack table size - it should be decrease cpu load.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same issue.  I can ping between the tunnel locations and the ports show to be open.  I continue to not be able to accept inbound traffic from the internet to my Tunnel server.  tcpdump -i tun0 is not showing any traffic when I try and ping the IP from my personal computer.  I have tried adding any number of iptables and firewalld rules with no avail.  Any help would be idea.

Here is the IP tables rule I just added:

## iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 25

And port 25 is not responding from an external source:
Host is up.

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
25/tcp filtered smtp